# How do I redirect the user to his/her profile after signing in. An after_sign_in method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Happy Thursday everyone, I had a quick question on routes and redirecting. I am working on a rails assignment that asks that I redirect the router to his/her profile after signing in. How would I go about doing that? An after_sign_in method? Here is my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :users

  get 'welcome/index'
  root :to => 'welcome#index'
end
```

Users Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
   def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
   end
end
```

devise/sessions (Login Page)

```
<h2>Sign in</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter email" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter password" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
          <%= f.label :remember_me, class: 'checkbox' do %>
            <%= f.check_box :remember_me %> Remember me
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Application Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    user_show_path
  end

   protected
   def configure_permitted_parameters
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
   end
end
```

I tried defining a after_sign_in_path in the application controller but recieve this error: undefined local variable or method `user_show_path'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL helper you need to call is `user_path(resource)` instead of `user_show_path`. (Devise will pass the current user as the resource for you.)

Check out the [Rails guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for details about the helpers that are generated when using `resources` in your routes.

Comment: Thank you, thank you! I will make sure to check the guide, but just to confirm. The resource parameter is the user_id being sent into the user_path?

Comment: It's actually a user object: the same thing that's returned when you call `#current_user`.